# how can i deal with the static parameters and static functions in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, static-variables, static-functions

```
public class C {
  public static string a;
 public static string b;

public C(String a, String b){
this.a=a;
this.b=b;
}
public void addString(){
 String result=a+b;
}
public static JSONObjet functionA(){
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
try { 
jsonobject.put(key1, a);
jsonobject.put(key2,b);
} catch(JsonException e){
******}
return jsonobject;}}
```

if put the parameters before init{}, then the functionA() can not recognize the a and b. If put the parameters into the companion object{}, the init can not recognize the a and b. How to convert this class to kotlin? what is your suggestion?

```
Class C{

     fun addString(){
     var result:String=a+b
    }
     init {
    this.a=a
    this.b=b
            }
        companion object {
       var a:String?=null
       var b:String?=null
       @JVMStatic
       fun functionA(): JSONObject?{
       var jsonobject = JSONObject()
    try { 
    jsonobject.put(key1, a)
    jsonobject.put(key2,b)
    } catch(JsonException e){
    ******}
    return jsonobject
    }}}
```

Comment: The Java class itself has kind of a bizarre design. Why would every arbitrary instance of a class overwrite the same static members and carry no state of their own?

Comment: The problem with your implementation isn't the order of initialization. It's that you have no explicit constructor for your class, so you have no variables to work with to set the static members to. Also, you will need to use `Companion.a` instead of `this.a`.

Comment: Hi, tenfour04,    fun addString() is just a normal method example that needs to use these two static parameters. this class with two static parameters, several not static methods which need call these two static parameters. One static method which needs call these two static parameters. And also one constructor.

Comment: hi, tenfour04, thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try the Companion.a and Companion.b to see. I will update it later, thank you

Comment: What I mean is why does the class overwrite the static members? Now, no instance of the class has any guarantee of what the static members are. They could be whatever the most recent instantiation passed. So why pass them through the constructor in the first place if they have nothing to do with that particular instance?

Comment: Hi,Tenfour04, i just convert the java to kotlin, i need to keep all parameters and method to be the same with previous java, then other class call this class method will not crash. So if before the parameters are static, i need to keep them to be static. That is the reason i need to keep them. And if the 4 parameters are not set to be static, try catch block can not access these parameters at all. So in java classes, the 4 parameters are static.

Comment: hi, tenfour04, I used the companion. a  and companion object. a. all of them have the error, it can not work. it showed the red curve line under it. it does not work. do you have other idea? ok, i found the solution, use the C.a and C.b, directly use the class to call the parameters, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The strict equivalent of your code is similar to what you have, except that you're missing the constructor parameters, and you need to use `Companion` instead of `this` to specify the companion's properties.

```
class C (a: String, b: String) {

    init {
        Companion.a = a
        Companion.b = b
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        var a: String? = null
        @JvmField
        var b: String? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun functionA(): JSONObject{
            val jsonObject = JSONObject()
            try {
                jsonObject.put(key1, a)
                jsonObject.put(key2, b)
            } catch (e: JsonException){
                //******
            }
            return jsonObject
        }
    }
}
```

Though I must say, I cannot recommend a design like this. It's a nasty abuse of statics.

Comment: init {
        Companion.a = a
        Companion.b = b
    }        this one does not work. must use C.a=a     C.b=b   , by its class call